# правка истории удаленной ветки в GIT

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-push

Cитуация такая, вот лог гита(после изменений) : [image]

До изменений под коммитом был коммит с таким же именем (`AgentsSimulation.Issue#1700 fixes`), и это все было запушено на сервер.

Я делаю интерактивный rebase (результат вы видите на картинке) Примечательно, что для мержа сверху(последний коммит в истории) я сделал pick. Далее делаю `push --force` он проходит, но история не изменяется на сервере(два коммита с одинаковым именем `AgentsSimulation.Issue#1700 fixes` остались).

Складывается впечатление, что сравнив sha мержей гит решил, что все up-to-date.

Comment: а в чём вопрос?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin правильно ли я понимаю, что при push force, гит будет править все комиты по цепочке , у которых sha отличается?

Comment: нет, конечно. «править коммиты» git вообще никогда не будет. когда вы даёте команду `git push`, недостающие в целевом репозитории объекты загружаются в него. но если между «верхними» коммитами в целевой и в исходной ветке нет прямой связи потомок-наследник, то (по умолчанию) идёт «отлуп». выполнив после этого `push` с параметром `--force` вы отправляете объекты принудительно. при этом как минимум один коммит в целевом репозитории останется «бесхозным» и будет удалён при garbage collection.

Comment: переписывание истории в bare-репозитории, имеющем больше одного клона (из которого и производится перезаписывание) — не лучшая идея. подозреваю, что после того, как вы перезаписали историю, кто-то в репозитории-клоне сделал `git pull` а затем `git push`, и вся ваша перезапись «пошла прахом»: в клонированном репозитории оказались «все» коммиты и плюс к ним ещё и «merge-коммит». продолжение в следующем комментарии.

Comment: *удачную* перезапись истории можно осуществить, например, если во *всех* клонах после отправки «перезаписывающего» коммита выполнить вместо `git pull` команды `git fetch; git reset origin/master`. можно и не «вместо», а после, но главное *до* выполнения `git push`. ну и, конечно, надо не забывать сохранить куда-то локальные изменения (если есть), ведь `git reset` их тоже уничтожит.

Comment: Если вы переписывали коммиты, то sha1 у них не могут быть одинаковыми. `rebase` тоже является переписыванием, т.к. он по сути создает новые коммиты.

Comment: @NickVolynkin "переписыванием" - это означает pick. Тоесть мерж на картинке - pick. А остальные 2 комита(с одинаковыми именами) сделал squash и pick. После этого форс пуш не сделал ожидаемого (сжатие 2х коммитов ) никто другой не работает с репозиторием

Comment: Хм. Если `git push -f` проходит, а история не изменяется, может `push` в другую ветку идет? `git remote show remotename` что показывает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin не знаю что показывает. Я смотрю историю коммитов гитлаба

Comment: @NickVolynkin зато помогло : для мержа поставить edit и после такого комита , пуш форс меняет историю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы история поменялась, надо на комите-мерже поставить edit, а не pick